# Calling models and their methods in external scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to access an activerecord model using rails runner. I passed the following: `rails runner "TabAccount.find_by_id(1).screen_name"`. I know this model is valid because I can use it and see the entry within my Rails app.

Ultimately I want to make a class that's a child of `TabAccount` and I'm getting hung up on that. I imagine the script would look something along the lines of this:

```
require Rails.root.join('app', 'models', 'tab_account.rb')
class TwitterAccount < TabAccount

  def initialize()
    @screen_name = TabAccount.find_by_id(1).screen_name
  end
end
```

Can I assume I'm pretty close and there's some nitpick detail I've overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

For this specific problem what I was getting hung up on was to make sure I could access the model and apparently all I had to do to validate that was to put in `rails r "puts TabAccount.find_by_id(1).screen_name"`. And then I do the same thing in my script to validate the model in that context.